# shortest_paths errorL: Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way

Tags: python, igraph

I am trying to call the shortest_paths() function for a relatively large network ( IGRAPH DN-- 13679 76741 -- ).
Unexpectedly, I got the following error:

> "Assertion failed: q->stor_begin != 0, file
>   c:\dev\igraph\igraph-0.6.5-msvc\src\dqueue.pmt, line 284
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information. "

what does this error mean?

```
g = Graph.Read_Ncol('file.edgelist')
g.delete_vertices(g.vs.select(_degree=0))
g.vs["color"] = "Green"
summary(g)  
t = time.time()
g.shortest_paths()
print time.time() - t
```

Comment: You should post the relevant code snippets so we have some clue what the problem is

Comment: This is probably a bug in the C core of the igraph library, but we cannot tell you more without seeing your actual graph. Please file this as a bug report in https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/issues and upload your graph somewhere so we can take a look at it. If we confirm that this is a bug in the C core, we will migrate your bug report to https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues .

Comment: Thanks @Tamás, I will do that. FYI, I've tried the same code using R, and it works perfect!